# group two variables(in rows) in R to create one variable

Tags: r, variables, group-by

I have a data frame where

```
Disease       Genemutation   Mean.   Total No of pateints  No.of pateints.  
cancertype1    BRCA1         1               10                  2
cancertype2    BRCA2        5                10                  3
cancertype3    BRCA2        7                10                  4
cancertype1    BRCA1        8                10                  1
cancertype3    BRCA2        4                10                  4
cancertype2    BRCA1        6                10                  1
```

how do I create an new variable called `cancertype 4` (from `cancer type 3` and `cancer type 2`) that includes the number of patients that have it as a result of merging the two variable?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `replace` with `%in%` to replace those values (assuming 'Disease' is `character` class)

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Disease = replace(Disease,
        Disease %in% c("cancertype2", "cancertype3"), "cancertype4")) %>%
   summarise(TotalNoofpateints = sum(TotalNoofpateints))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Disease     TotalNoofpateints
#  <chr>                   <int>
#1 cancertype1                20
#2 cancertype4                40
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(
  Total.No.of.pateints ~ Disease,
  transform(
    df,
    Disease = replace(Disease, Disease %in% c("cancertype2", "cancertype3"), "cancertype4")
  ),
  sum
)
```

giving

```
      Disease Total.No.of.pateints
1 cancertype1                   20
2 cancertype4                   40
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Disease = c("cancertype1", "cancertype2", "cancertype3", 
"cancertype1", "cancertype3", "cancertype2"), Genemutation = c("BRCA1",
"BRCA2", "BRCA2", "BRCA1", "BRCA2", "BRCA1"), Mean. = c(1L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 4L, 6L), Total.No.of.pateints = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L,
10L, 10L), No.of.pateints. = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```